# Accessing 'hidden' directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to AngularJs directives and I'm trying to understand how the scope works. I think I understand it well but then I run into a problem like the following.
My directive:

```
<ng-view>
    <div my-directive ng-click="foo()" >...</div>
</ng-view>
```

Directive code:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.foo = function(){...}
    }
})
```

I was expecting `foo()` to fire when clicking the element but it doesn't. Checking the scope with batarang I see the scope exists(id:#003) with the rootScope as its parent but when clicking the element or its children the scope is the root(id:#002), I also checked with `angular.element($('div[my-directive]')).scope()` thinking it could be a batrang issue but the result was the same.

**UPDATE:** I think I found the cause of the problem, in my real app the element using the directive is inside an `ngView` directive, when I put my directive outside of the ngView the properties I defined in the link function are now visible in the scope(rootScope). I guess it's due to the async load but I need to confirm, in [this fiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaS45/) I used ngView with a static template but it didn't work(it works, I couldn't reproduce the problem).

Comment: Creating scope functions inside directives is not the way to go. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok, go it! Is convention or simply it doesn't work, and why?
Independently the scope should be visible/accessible, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you create an example at http://plnkr.co ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use a template and transclusion in your directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
   return {
      template: '<div ng-click="foo()" ng-transclude></div>',
      transclude: true,
      controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         $scope.foo = function () {...};
      }
   };
});
```

And your html:

```
<div my-directive>...<div>
```

The reason this works is you define the `foo` function in the scope *within* the directive. In your original attempt, `foo` is expected to be in the parent scope. While it is possible for your directive to change the parent scope's `foo` definition, this is unlikely what you want. You're essentially asking your directive users to know about the directive's internally defined `foo` function. It's a bit awkward/backwards.

Comment: I would suggest that any functions you expose to the scope are exposed in an api object ex: $scope.myDirective = {foo: foo}. This way you are less likely in shadowing a parent variable/function AND it's clearer that these functions are directive api functions

Answer (score 1):

Since the directive does not specify a new scope (`scope: true`), or an isolate scope (`scope: { ... }`), or use transclusion, it will use the "scope in affect" in the HTML.

If your directive is used outside a controller, it will use $rootScope, and `foo` will be defined on it:

```
<div my-directive ng-click="foo()" >click me</div>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

[image]

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NM374/1/)</kbd>

If your directive is used inside a controller, it will use that controller's scope:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div my-directive ng-click="foo()" >click me</div>
</div>
```

[image]

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NM374/3/)</kbd>

Comment: According to this, `foo` or any other property I attach to the scope in the link function should be visible on the rootScope, but as I said when I check the scope of the element with the directive it's the rootScope the properties I declared are not there.

Comment: @olanod, to my first fiddle, add `console.log(scope)` after the `alert()` and you'll see it is the rootScope.  Maybe you can provide a fiddle or plunker of your problem, since my first fiddle shows that `foo` is added to the rootScope (the pictures are generated from Angular data structures).

Comment: Yes I see the properties are there, I created a fiddle myself and it also worked. I'm investigating...